# python xlsxwriter change row height for all rows in the sheet

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Python xlsxwriter, change row height for all rows in the sheet, 
following is available but apply to single row

```
worksheet.set_row(0, 20)  # Set the height of Row 1 to 20.
```

Want to change height of all the rows sheet.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To set the height of all rows in XlsxWriter, efficiently*, you can use the [`set_default_row()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/worksheet.html#worksheet-set-default-row) method:

```
worksheet.set_default_row(20)
```

(*) This is efficient because it uses an Excel optimisation to adjust the row heights with a single XML element. By contrast, using `set_row()` for each of the ~ 1 million rows would required 1 million XML elements and would lead to a very large file.